# Choose custom GraalVM version to build Micronaut native image

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to build a Micronaut application as a native image for AWS Lambda. But somehow, the build is not picking up the GraalVM version which is installed locally, but rather it downloads the GraalVM version on its own. I have searched few of the documentations, but didn't find anywhere how we can disable/change this behavior.

Here is how I build the native image: `./gradlew clean buildNativeLambda -Pmicronaut.runtime=lambda`

Have already set the `JAVA_HOME` and `GRAALVM_HOME` to my custom GraalVM version.

Even tried passing following params, but nothing seems to be working: `./gradlew clean -Porg.gradle.java.installations.auto-download=false -Porg.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false -Porg.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JAVA_HOME buildNativeLambda -Pmicronaut.runtime=lambda`

Also tried adding below params to the `gradle.properties`, but nothing worked:

```
# Disable Gradle automatic download of Java SDKs
org.gradle.java.installations.auto-download=false
# Disable auto-detection of Java installations
org.gradle.java.installations.auto-detect=false
# Setup explicitly that the Java version to use
# should be the one from the JAVA_HOME environment variable
org.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JAVA_HOME
```

It always generates dockerfile with below steps, where it automatically downloads some GraalVM version on its own. Below are the truncated build logs:

```
.
.
.
> Task :generateResourcesConfigFile
[native-image-plugin] Resources configuration written into D:\Project\build\native\generated\generateResourcesConfigFile\resource-config.json

> Task :dockerfileNative
Dockerfile written to: D:\Project\build\docker\native-main\DockerfileNative

> Task :dockerBuildNative
Building image using context 'D:\Project\build\docker\native-main'.
Using Dockerfile 'D:\Project\build\docker\native-main\DockerfileNative'
Using images 'project'.
Step 1/27 : FROM amazonlinux:latest AS graalvm
---> 01bdb519be20
Step 2/27 : ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
---> Using cache
---> 6bd9aa9f16ff
Step 3/27 : RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ libc6-dev zlib1g-dev curl bash zlib zlib-devel zlib-static zip tar gzip
---> Using cache
---> b0a55dbb7834
Step 4/27 : RUN curl -4 -L https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz -o /tmp/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz
---> Using cache
---> 45a9b3d523a3
.
.
.
```

See `Step 4/27` in above build logs. How can we disable that, and instead make it use the GraalVM version which is installed locally on the host machine where build is being generated?

`build.gradle`:

```
.
.
.
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("lambda_provided")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.package.*")
    }
}

tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    args(
        "-XX:MaximumHeapSizePercent=80",
        "-Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0",
        "-Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true"
    )
}

graalvmNative.binaries.all {
    buildArgs.add("--no-server --pgo-instrument -J-Xmx12g -J-Xms4g -O0")
}
```

Have followed below links, but didn't get any success yet:

- https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/snapshot/
- https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin/issues/516
- https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin/pull/530

**Edit 2022-12-12:**

Automatically generated `DockerfileNative`:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest AS graalvm
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ libc6-dev zlib1g-dev curl bash zlib zlib-devel zlib-static zip tar gzip
RUN curl -4 -L https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz -o /tmp/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf /tmp/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz -C /tmp && mv /tmp/graalvm-ce-java11-22.1.0 /usr/lib/graalvm
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
RUN /usr/lib/graalvm/bin/gu install native-image
CMD ["/usr/lib/graalvm/bin/native-image"]
ENV PATH=/usr/lib/graalvm/bin:${PATH}
FROM graalvm AS builder
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY layers/libs /home/app/libs
COPY layers/classes /home/app/classes
COPY layers/resources /home/app/resources
COPY layers/application.jar /home/app/application.jar
RUN mkdir /home/app/config-dirs
COPY config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile /home/app/config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile
RUN native-image -cp /home/app/libs/*.jar:/home/app/resources:/home/app/application.jar --no-fallback -H:Name=application -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.configure=ALL-UNNAMED -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=/home/app/config-dirs/generateResourcesConfigFile -H:Class=com.project.Application --no-server -J-Xmx12g -J-Xms4g -O0
FROM amazonlinux:latest
WORKDIR /function
RUN yum install -y zip
COPY --from=builder /home/app/application /function/func
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh" >> bootstrap && echo "set -euo pipefail" >> bootstrap && echo "./func -XX:MaximumHeapSizePercent=80 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true -Djava.library.path=$(pwd)" >> bootstrap
RUN chmod 777 bootstrap
RUN chmod 777 func
RUN zip -j function.zip bootstrap func
ENTRYPOINT ["/function/func"]
```

Comment: can you add the DockerfileNative?

Comment: @saw303 I have already added a part of it which I though is necessary. Do you need full DockerfileNative?

Comment: I see the docker build output but no Dockerfile. That one would be helpful to see what Micronaut Geadle plugin generated

Comment: @saw303 Just added the Dockerfilenative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `buildNativeLambda` task of the Micronaut Gradle plugin you delegate the build to the Docker daemon to build the image. Your local GraalVM installation is **never** used when build Docker images.

As you can see in your `DockerfileNative` the build is based on the `amazonlinux:latest` Docker image and then downloads (line 4) GraalVM 22.1.0 Community Edition. This is done by the Docker daemon running on your machine (or a build machine), completely ignoring your local setup (GraalVM installation).

```bash
RUN curl -4 -L https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.1.0/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz -o /tmp/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.1.0.tar.gz
```

When you take a look at the Gradle plugin [source code](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin/blob/95ef46e14f0d13a3a06eecbde39655b6984cff9e/docker-plugin/src/main/java/io/micronaut/gradle/docker/NativeImageDockerfile.java#L404) you see, that you have the possibility to configure the GraalVM version. This will change the generated download link in line 4.

IMO you can overwrite these values and configure the GraalVM version yourself in your `build.gradle` file.

```
tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    graalVersion = '22.3.0' // use 22.3.0 instead of 22.1.0
}
```

Comment: Legend! How did you get to know about this configuration? I mean is there any documentation?

Comment: that did build the project with desired GraalVM version, but it is failing to run the project. It throws `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` bean not found exception. Just if I remove this `graalVersion` it works absolutely fine. Any idea on this?

Comment: Create a new question and add the details. Otherwise this question and answer gets very defocused